# Error building my first Javascript library

Tags: javascript, css, html

I´ve doing some work in Javascript for my ASP.NET application. I got after a while a lot of views with extensive Javascript functionalities, but all replicated in different views. Now I decided I have to make things easier and decided to start building my own Javascript libraries.

So, this is the code I first came for, to have a `paintedText` that I will control on screen (this is a library prototype, so I took a simple function to test. Of course this can be done easily without a library).

The library:

```
/*
 * My first Javascript library
 */

paintedText = (function () {
    "use strict";

    paintedText = paintedText || {};

    paintedText = (function (id) {

        //Private Property
        var version = "1.0.0";

        //Public Property
        var color = null;

        var elementId = id;

        //Public Method
        setColor = function (color) {
            var dom = getMyDOM(document.getElementById(id));
            domElement.style = "color : " + color;
        }

        //Private Method
        function getElementObj() {

            if (elementId === undefined) 
                alert("Undefined " + elementId);
            else
                return document.getElementById(elementid);
        }
    })
})
```

And the index.html page:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myLib.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="test">
 <h1>TEXT TO CHANGE COLOR</h1>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var item = new paintedText ('test');
        alert ('Will change color.');
        item.setColor('red');
    });

</script>
</body>
```

I keep receiving a message that `paintedText` does not exists and I´m stuck with that. I hope someone can help me to move further...

So the questions are:

1. Why is that code not working ?
2. Is my code protected (I need to insert into my pages and make
   sure my variables will be unique) ?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: You're trying to set some property on `dom`. That doesn't appear anywhere in your code up until that point.

Comment: Yes, this is true. I have edited and fixed this, but makes no difference as the error comes when loading the myLib.js - paintedText is not defined - in the very first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, if you want to create an instance of an IIFE, you need a constructor function.

Also, `dom` is define inside its own function.

How about something like this:

```
var PaintedText = (function(){

    function pt(id){
        this.element = document.getElementById(id);
    }

    pt.prototype.setColor = function(color){
        if(!this.element) throw new ReferenceError('element not found');
        this.element.style.color = color;
    };

    return pt;

})();

var pt = new PaintedText('test');
pt.setColor('red');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U6KS2/

Comment: It´s nice from your and your given code works, but I really insist in my IIFE, as this is my learing point now. I would like to know what I´m doing in the wrong way (see edited code)...

Comment: Try defining the variable ie `var paintedText = (function () {`. As I mentioned you need a constructor funciton in order to pass in unique id:s for each instance like in my example